# Angular: how to loop through JSON in controller and display in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, angularjs

I am learning a Angular and I'm stuck with one task. I have three parts in my app a View, service and controller,
View look like this:

```
<body ng-app="ForecastApp">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">

          <p class="navbar-brand">Week Forecast</p>

      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid"  class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <h2><span class="label label-info">Search for a City</span></h2>
          <div class="input-group">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City name...">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
          </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <h1 class="page-header">{{ fiveDay.city.name }}</h1>

          <div class="forecast" ng-repeat="day in fiveDay.days">

              </div>
              </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The service look like this:

```
app.factory('forecast', ['$http', function($http) { 
  return $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?q=Warsaw&units=metric&mo') 
            .success(function(data) { 
              return data; 
            }) 
            .error(function(err) { 
              return err; 
            }); 
}]);
```

And the controller look like this:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'forecast', function($scope, forecast) {

  forecast.success(function(data) { 
    $scope.fiveDay = data; 
  });

}]);
```

Data for this lesson is take from the rest api from here http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?q=Warsaw&units=metric&mo

How can I go throw all this json resposne and display all the items from the array "list" from this json, for example to look like this:

Date: "2015-06-12 15:00:00"
description: "few clouds"
temp: 26.82
pressure: 1015.2

Comment: Post the JSON please.

Comment: @TheHeadRush here: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?q=Warsaw&units=metric&mo

Comment: http://pastebin.com/htiWAFjZ

Comment: There is no `days` property for that JSON response, there is a `list` property where you meaning to use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see its simple JSON you can traverse through it using `.` & whenever required mention `index` of it to get the value.

**Code**

```
$scope.fiveDays = data.list
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="forecast" ng-repeat="day in fiveDays ">
   <div>Date : {{dt|date: 'yyyy-dd-MM'}}</div>
   <div>description: {{weather[0].description}}</div>
   <div>temp: {{main.temp}}</div>
   <div>pressure: {{main.pressure}}</div>
</div>
```

Different [**angular date filter format**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)